# getting unknown option `--tag' when trying to run a scenario using nightwatch

Tags: node.js, cucumber, nightwatch.js

I'm using the below command to run one of test case using nightwatch, but getting the below error
npm run test:cucumber -- --tag Seleniumeasy

automation@1.0.0 test:cucumber C:\Users****\Desktop\Automation

> mkdirp report && cucumber-js --require cucumber.conf.js --require step-definitions --format node_modules/cucumber-pretty --format json:report/cucumber_report.json "--tag" "Seleniumeasy"

error: unknown option `--tag'
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! automation@1.0.0 test:cucumber:`mkdirp report && cucumber-js --require cucumber.conf.js --require step-definitions --format node_modules/cucumber-pretty --format json:report/cucumber_report.json "--tag" "Seleniumeasy"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the automation@1.0.0 test:cucumber script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

Comment: I'm not particularly familiar with Cucumber, but it's probable that some dependency is missing. Try running it without the --tag argument. Also, make sure that cucumber is installed and it's the correct version. also, why is there an empty argument -- ? Maybe you ought to try it without that as well?

Comment: @QualiT that is the format for running a particular test scenario using nightwatch

Comment: Does it run for other scenarios?

Comment: No, if I try to insert 'tag' option it throws that error

Comment: Make sure you have installed everything correctly. Those npm dependancies are probably the problem. Did you copy you automation tests over a whole folder and maybe you did not actually install node, or all of the other required modules?

Comment: You might need to make sure you installed bower, gulp, cucumber.

Comment: Thanks for the help!.. I have solved it.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
npm run test:cucumber -- --tags "@Seleniumeasy"
```